# How can I print two return values using .format()?

Tags: python

I am creating a function to find the min and max of a dataset, and I get an error when I try to use two return values. I cannot figure out how to format the print function to accept two values that are in the same function.

**CODE:**

```
data=[1,5,3,8,9,7,2]

def minMaxList(data):
    min=data[0]
    max=data[-1]
    for i in data:
        if i>max:
            max=i
        if i<min:
            min=i
    return (min, max)   

print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(minMaxList(data)))
```

**ERROR:**

```
Type Error: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__
```

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to know: there are built-in functions `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an asterisk (`*`) before the tuple to unpack it:

```
print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(*minMaxList(data)))
```

with this addition the program outputs:

```
The min and max of this population is 1.00 and 2.00
```

Alternatively,

```
min, max = minMaxList(data)
print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(min, max))
```

gives the same output and may be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use unpacking operator `*`
So your code should look like

```
print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(*minMaxList(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = minMaxList(data)
print("The min and max of this population is {} and {}. format (val[0], val[1])
```

Comment: Sure, but it is so much nicer to do `min_population, max_population = minMaxList(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet:

```
data=[1,5,3,8,9,7,2]
def minMaxList(data):
    min=data[0]
    max=data[-1]
    for i in data:
        if i>max:
            max=i
        if i<min:
            min=i
    return (min, max)
print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(minMaxList(data)))
```

Here you get an issue because the function `minMaxList()` returns a tuple/iterative object which needs to be unpacked to resolve issue here, to do this

use * before function call, the print statement should be:

```
print("The min and max of this population is {:.2f} and {:.2f}".format(*minMaxList(data)))
```

[image: Output Looks like this]